# Is localhost (HTTP) sending API key to HTTPS endpoint secure?

Tags: https

Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but if I'm developing on localhost (HTTP) and my app from local development sends a request to an external HTTPS API endpoint with an API key included, is the API key communicated securely?

The endpoint is using HTTPS, but the app itself is not. Is the latter irrelevant?